# Gir15 cuneiform is esh2 homograph?

Tags: written-language, software, dead-languages

I was unable to find a cuneiform for Sumerian (Akkadian?) ĝir<sub>15</sub> (as in [ki-en-ĝir<sub>15</sub>](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sumer)) in the unicode character database ([cuneiform namelist](http://unicode.org/charts/nameslist/n_12000.html)) .. however, according to [ePSD](http://psd.museum.upenn.edu/epsd/nepsd-frame.html), it seems that it has the same cuneiform as eš<sub>2</sub>.. compare [ĝir [NATIVE]](http://psd.museum.upenn.edu/epsd/epsd/e2182.html) and [eš [FLOUR]](http://psd.museum.upenn.edu/epsd/epsd/e1415.html) or [eš [ROPE]](http://psd.museum.upenn.edu/epsd/epsd/e1416.html), both seem to use `U+120A0` "" character.

Is it an example of homographs, or is the story more complicated?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, eš2 and gir15 are two "readings" (as one says in Assyriology) of the same sign.

Comment: Yes, look at the ePSD site. You have already given the links.